# Get the thread of a running task

Tags: multithreading

I want to get the thread of a task that is running and not completed. The language I am using is c#, and what I am trying to do is if some action cannot be completed which is locking one of my file, in that case I want to get the thread of that action and destroy the thread and release the file. thats what I want to do.

var task= Task.Run(() => SomeFunction){
getting thread code for the incomplete task here}

Comment: Please, try to add more details to your question. What language/platform are you using? What information are you expecting to get from the task?

Comment: The language I am using is c#, and what I am trying to do is if some action cannot be completed which is locking one of my file, in that case I want to get the thread of that action and destroy the thread and release the file. thats what I want to do.

Comment: Please, add this description in the question. It will increase your chance to get a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the Id?

I think you can access it by `Task.CurrentId`

As stated on [this document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentthread?view=netframework-4.8)

As for completion, you can use `Task.IsCompleted`.
As states [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_IsCompleted).

Comment: I have used it, but what I want to do is if the task is not completed and if it goes inside the if statement than i want to get the thread for that specific task that is running and is not complete.